# Silverlight: how to handle standard assemblies (part 3)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, xap, dynamically-loaded-xap

When Silverlight4 application is build the 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll' assembly is not putting into a separated file zip-file, it is in the XAP-file instead.

To be consistent, here are links to previous questions of the 'How to handle standard assemblies' topic:
[[Silverlight: how to handle standard assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329731/silverlight-how-to-handle-standard-assemblies][Silverlight): how to handle standard assemblies]
[[Silverlight: how to handle standard assemblies (part 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376143/silverlight-how-to-handle-standard-assemblies-part-2][Silverlight): how to handle standard assemblies (part 2)]

Here is a list of actions done:

1. Deleted references on 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll' assembly from Silverlight project and all its libraries;
2. Copied this dll into "C:\Project\DLL" folder;
3. "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.extmap.xml" file was created in the folder with the following content:

   < ?xml version="1.0"?>

   > ```
   > <manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   >           xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   >   <assembly>
   >     <name>Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight</name>
   >     <version>2.0.414.0</version>
   >     <publickeytoken>31bf3856ad364e35</publickeytoken>
   >     <relpath>Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll</relpath>
   >     <extension downloadUri="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.zip" />
   >   </assembly>
   > </manifest>
   > ```

(version number and public key token get from assembly itself).

4. Added reference to the assembly into Silverlight project and 1 Silverlight class library that is used by the project;
5. Performed full rebuild of the Silverlight-projects, rebuilded a web-site.

I am expecting file "Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.zip" to be appeared in the "ClientBin" folder of the web site... but it doesn't.. And I don't have any idea why..

Probably you know something helpful? If so, please let me know.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed the [Unity Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678312.aspx).

I added two files to the default installation folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Unity Application Block 2.0 for Silverlight\Bin
```

**Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.extmap.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <assembly>
    <name>Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight</name>
    <version>2.0.414.0</version>
    <publickeytoken>31bf3856ad364e35</publickeytoken>
    <relpath>Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.dll</relpath>
    <extension downloadUri="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.zip" />
  </assembly>
</manifest>
```

and **Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.extmap.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <assembly>
    <name>Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation</name>
    <version>2.0.414.0</version>
    <publickeytoken>31bf3856ad364e35</publickeytoken>
    <relpath>Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</relpath>
    <extension downloadUri="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.zip" />
  </assembly>
</manifest>
```

I've never used the Unity Framework, so I decided that I'd want to include both assemblies in the same ZIP file. To do that I set the `downloadUri` attribute of the `extension` element to be the same file name in both extmap.xml files. In this case, I used **Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.zip**.

I added a reference to the Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight assembly from a Silverlight 4.0 project.

Next, I checked the option: **Reduce XAP size by using application library caching** in the project properties of my Silverlight project.

Rebuilt the solution. Within the ClientBin folder of the host web application, a new Zip file Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverlight.zip had been added after the rebuild.

I'd suggest following the method I used and see if that works for you. Try rebuilding the solution with that option unchecked (and clear the client bin folder). Clean, and rebuild with it checked and see if that has any effect.

Comment: Yes, I did in the same way,... Unfortunately it doesn't create a zip file for Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Silverligh. I also tried to uncheck and check "Reduce..." option again: nothing changed... :(